# when does data to output file is written in a map reduce architecture?How can i use processed reducer output data in reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using hadoop version:1.0.0

After processing each reducer input key i am collecting the output.But it is not written to actual output file. I am trying to use processed intermediate output for processing further input keys.How can i do this?

Could you please suggest me how to use that intermediate data.When does mapreduce write data to output file?.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is something against the MR paradigm. And, as any deviation from the concept has consiquences. 
Technically data is passed to the OutputFormat and it is his discretion to push it to output. I think it is written during the job, but You might have some delay before seeing it. 
I think it would be easier for you to exolicitely accumulate processed data in reducer and use it, although this solution has inhenrent problem. You can face out of memory if there is enought keys. 
I would suggest using two MR jobs, or some other techinques to make reducer stateless or at least limit amount of data it can accumulate.